# TSQL equivalent of Linq SelectMany

Tags: linq, t-sql

I would like the resultset that consists of the union of queries performed based on each row of an outer `SELECT` query.  How do I do this?

As an example:

```
create table Person
(
    Id int,
    Age int
)

create table Movie
(
    Id int,
    Title varchar(500),
    AgeRestriction int
)
```

I would like a resultset that shows me, for every person, which movies that person would be allowed to watch.

UPDATE: Ok, so as it turns out there is no "equivalent" of `SelectMany` in TSQL since the model is completely different, as the author of the correct answer has pointed out an inner join will do the job just fine.

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected results, sentence to me doesn't make much sense.

Comment: could you show us an example data and desired output?

Comment: @MladenPrajdic - hi mladen it's Jon :).

Comment: Hi Jon. Nice seeing you here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear but it sounds like you might want `CROSS APPLY`

Random Example

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.* /*DISTINCT for UNION semantics*/
FROM   master..spt_values v
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 2 *
                    FROM   sys.columns c
                    WHERE  c.name > v.name
                    ORDER BY c.name) ca
```

Edit. Following clarification you just need a `JOIN`

```
SELECT P.Id,
       M.Title
FROM   Person P
       JOIN Movie M
         ON M.AgeRestriction <= P.Age
```

Comment: Many forms of SelectMany can be implemented as a join as well